# Extremely Strange behavior of my own loss function written in keras (always output similar values)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a CNN based deep learning algorithm to provide continuous ranking of a set of images. My plan is to feed the network with batches of images that is already ranked in the correct order, and evaluate the ranking errors in the custom loss function, hopefully the network can learn how to produce a relative number to indicating the position of a given image in a sequence.

I have come up with the simple custom loss function as below:

```py
def my_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    #diff = y_pred[1:,:] - y_pred[:-1, :] //previous implementation, same problem
    indx1 = tf.range(1, 128)
    indx2 = tf.range(0, 127)
    diff = tf.gather(y_pred, indx1) - tf.gather(y_pred, indx2)
    order_loss = -K.sum(K.log(K.sigmoid(diff)+K.epsilon()))

    return order_loss
```

As you can see that I actually don't need the y-true data, so I generated a dummy y_true data just to avoid the checking error by keras.

The strange problem I have now is this loss function always starts with almost the same value when I run it, even after I changed the return to `2*order_loss` or change `K.sum` to `K.mean` or other functions. In training, the loss can reduce very slowly and will plateau quickly. I could not think of any reason that might cause this problem, did anyone have similar experience or know how to solve this problem?

---

Update:

Even after I changed the loss function to:

```
def my_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = alpha*y_pred  # alpha is a constant
    order_loss = -K.sum(K.log(K.sigmoid(diff)+K.epsilon()))
    return order_loss
```

it still has the same problem, when I change the alpha value, the output doesn't change accordingly. The int_shape of y_pred is (none, 1).

---

Comment: Not exactly clear what the loss function is trying to do. Care to explain a bit more?

Comment: My expected output for the batch is an array of numbers in increasing order, which should indicate correct ranking in that case, so I am trying to punish the wrong output( decreasing order) by comparing adjacent outputs in a batch.

Comment: Based on my experiments, it seems as long as I do the slicing of the batch output, the loss function will behave weirdly, but keras will not report any error

Comment: 128 is my batch size

Comment: my network output is a single float number, so y_pred shape is (batch_size, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to answer without exactly working with the problem, but I can suggest you to do some debugging inside the loss function. Here is an example of how you can print some stuff and see what is actually going in there.

```
def my_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = y_pred[1:,:] - y_pred[:-1, :] 
    order_loss = -K.sum(K.log(K.sigmoid(diff)+K.epsilon()))

    # anything you like to print
    print_op = tf.print("\nDebug : ", diff, order_loss, K.get_variable_shape(y_pred))  
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]): # this will force the print_op to be run
        return K.identity(order_loss)
    #return K.identity(order_loss)
```

I hope this will be helpful for you to see if the shapes and values are as expected and if you see any discrepancies.
Let me know if you find anything fishy, and then we can take it forward.

Comment: If your `y_pred` is shaped `(batch_size, 1)`, your `diff` should be a vector of length `batch_size - 1`. You might need to decide if you want to add all the values (pos and neg).  Your problem might be somewhere other than the loss function as well. As I said it's a broad problem to answer without having a go at it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I tried your code to print out something, but it didn't work on my machine, I am using windows 10, keras2.2.4, tensorflow 1.13.1. I tried degug and printed out print_op manually, it only shows: ipdb> print(print_op)
name: "loss_1/dense_2_loss/PrintV2"
op: "PrintV2"
input: "loss_1/dense_2_loss/StringFormat"
attr {
  key: "output_stream"
  value {
    s: "stderr"
  }
}

Comment: I tried to print out int_shape and got:                                                            ipdb> print(K.int_shape(y_pred))
(None, 1)

ipdb> print(K.int_shape(diff))
(None, 1)

ipdb> print(K.int_shape(order_loss))
()

Comment: I found out that even after I changed the loss function to return K.sum(K.log(K.sigmoid(y_pred))), without any slicing, the loss function still behaves weirdly, and outputs same initial values after I multiply y_pred by 100

Comment: Could you show how you are calling the loss function? Also you can do a simple experiment of returning a scalar hard coded value as loss and check if you see that value.

Comment: About the `tf.print` it works for me but I will check the versions I use.

Comment: I changed my loss function to return 100.0+0*order_loss, but it doesn't return 100.0 as the loss, instead, something around 194.***, sooo strange! I will post my whole code in the main question section

Comment: just posted my full code, please take a look at it, thanks!